# reuse multiple scopes in another scope to create search multiple fields in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope

I'm creating scope for searching using form parameter but I don't know how to combine scope with conditions or call current scope.
Here is my source code

```
class Issue < ApplicationRecord

  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }

  scope :state, ->(flag = :open){
    where state: flag
  }

  scope :sort_by, ->(field = :github_id, sort_type = :asc){
    reorder({field.to_sym => (sort_type && sort_type.to_sym) || :asc })
  }

  scope :milestone, ->(milestone){
    where milestone: milestone
  }

  scope :assignee, ->(assignee){
    where assignee: assignee
  }

  scope :author, ->(author){
    where author: author
  }

  scope :search, ->(param={}){
    # assign result = default scope here and chain it using below scope
    sort_by(param[:sort_by],param[:sort_type]) if param[:sort_by].present?
    author(param[:author]) if param[:author].present?
    assignee(param[:assignee]) if param[:assignee].present?
    milestone(param[:milestone]) if param[:milestone].present?
  }

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a local variable:

```
scope :search, ->(param={}) {
  relation = all
  relation = relation.sort_by(param[:sort_by],param[:sort_type]) if param[:sort_by].present?
  relation = relation.author(param[:author]) if param[:author].present?
  relation = relation.assignee(param[:assignee]) if param[:assignee].present?
  relation = relation.milestone(param[:milestone]) if param[:milestone].present?
  relation
}
```

Comment: You can also use a plus sign to combine `ActiveRecord::Relation` collections but since all of them optional, it makes more sense to use a local variable. :)

Comment: Thanks alot, This is what I need. :D

Comment: @codyeatworld Maybe this is a silly question but what is a plus sign? Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 3):

Using plus signs (untested):

```
scope :search, ->(param={}) {
  all
  + relation.sort_by(param[:sort_by],param[:sort_type]) if param[:sort_by].present?
  + relation.author(param[:author]) if param[:author].present?
  + relation.assignee(param[:assignee]) if param[:assignee].present?
  + relation.milestone(param[:milestone]) if param[:milestone].present?
}
```

Another example would be:

`User.where(thing: true) + User.where(thing: false)`

Because they both return `ActiveRecord::Relation` object collections.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there's such a cool feature in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Yeah, I liked learning about that one too. Also, if you have duplicate records you can use `results.uniq` :)

Comment: By the way, I can't find the documentation about that `+`, where did you find that?

Comment: I'm not sure where it would be documented. I have a feeling it is because you can basically add anything together in Ruby.